# NameError: name 'mainloop' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

объясните пожалуйста почему так работает:

```
import tkinter

def recAction(*args):
    print('ddd')

root = tkinter.Tk()

row6 = tkinter.Frame(root, borderwidth = 10)
row6.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')
button = tkinter.Button(row6, text = 'Send', height = 20, width = 20, relief = 'raised', cursor = 'hand1', font = ('times', 14, 'bold'))
button.bind('<Button-1>', recAction)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

а так не работает:

```
import tkinter

def recAction():
    print('ddd')

root = tkinter.Tk()

row6 = tkinter.Frame(root, borderwidth = 10)
row6.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')
button = tkinter.Button(row6, text = 'Send', height = 20, width = 20, relief = 'raised', cursor = 'hand1', font = ('times', 14, 'bold'))
button.bind('<Button-1>', recAction)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

сообщение об ошибке такое:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Python33\projects\DVD_LIST\p3_dvd_list_shelve_3d_class_edit_menubar\q.py",
> line 14, in <module>
>     mainloop() NameError: name 'mainloop' is not defined

мне это не  понятно так как в интернетах много примеров именно второго типа. например [таких](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: ну трэйсбэк, хотя б, весь скопировал сюда

Comment: потому, что button.bind требует функцию с определенной сигнатурой. Если сигнатура не совпадает, то может быть все что угодно - все зависит от того, как передаются аргументы. А Вы пытаетесь ему подсунуть функцию без параметров видимо только на том основании, что Вам внутри функции аргументы не нужны.

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin а у меня и первый вариант ругается на mainloop. Правда, если запускать с REPL (real-eval-print-loop), то на mainloop выругается, но картинку покажет (там свой loop есть). Вы пишите 

      import tkinter

и, соответственно, никаких mainloop'ов у Вас нет (в отличие от tkinter.mainloop). python, однако.

Ну или дополните чем-нибудь типа 

     from tkinter import mainloop

Comment: @cyklop77: А можно попросить поправить свой код так, чтобы соответствовал PEP8 ?

Answer (score 3):

1. На вызов `mainloop` ругается потому, что эта функция определена внутри модуля `tkinter`. Нужно либо вызывать её как `tkinter.mainloop()`, либо включить её в пространство имен текущего модуля с помощью `from tkinter import mainloop` и вызывать просто как `mainloop()`.

   В данном случае имеет смысл вызывать метод `mainloop()` от объекта `root`: `root.mainloop()`
2. "Привязываемые" к событиям функции должны иметь как минимум один параметр, в который попадёт объект-событие. Опять же два варианта: смириться, и дать `tkinter` этот параметр, или объявить функцию `recAction` без параметров, а привязывать её через прослойку `lambda`, как предложил [alexlz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352/alexlz): `button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: recAction())`

Answer (score 0):

ну спасибо, помогли. хотя и я не понял почему именно нужно передавать аргумент, но теперь по крайней мере проблему буду решать следующим образом:
`button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: recAction(event))`
.......

```
def recAction(event):
    print('ddd')
```

и mainloop теперь буду записывать так:
`tkinter.mainloop` :)

Comment: Вы этот параметр не передаете, его передает "система" (в данном случае классы tkinter). А Вам возможно его нужно будет обработать. Код легче спроектировать, если заранее условиться о общем интерфейсе. А вот почему "система" передает этот параметр и что там будет - это уже к разработчикам библиотеки.

Comment: @KoVadim ну про event'ы-то в доках написано.

@Sergey Kalinin в чём сакральный смысл конструкции

     button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: recAction(event))

? И чем она в Вашем случае отличается от 

     button.bind('<Button-1>', recAction)

? Поскольку у recAction аргумент один, то лишняя прокладка из lambda не требуется. Вот если бы написали

     button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: recAction())

для recAction, объявленной без аргументов -- это было бы понятно -- избавляетесь от лишнего параметра...